# Looping into a list to get the previous value of a particular value within that list

Tags: python, list, loops

We have a list of strings here called list_strings `

```
list_strings =["john", "sarah", "bianca", "savie", "sandy", "john", "harry", "john", "debra", "john"]
```

If a specified value is "john" and can we get all the strings before john, so the output should look like this!`

```
result = ["none", "sandy", "harry", "debra]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```py
list_strings =["john", "sarah", "bianca", "savie", "sandy", "john", "harry", "john", "debra", "john"]
result = []
for i, j in enumerate(list_strings):
    if j == "john":
        if i:
            result.append(list_strings[i-1])
        else:
            result.append(None)
```

```
[None, 'sandy', 'harry', 'debra']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you an use the built-in `zip` method:

```
list_strings =["john", "sarah", "bianca", "savie", "sandy", "john", "harry", "john", "debra", "john"]

s = "john"

print([i for i, j in zip(list_strings[:-1], list_strings[1:]) if j == s])
```

Output:

```
['sandy', 'harry', 'debra']
```

In order to include the `"none"` for when the first string in the list is `"john"`, you can do:

```
list_strings =["john", "sarah", "bianca", "savie", "sandy", "john", "harry", "john", "debra", "john"]

s = "john"

result = []
if list_strings[0] == "john":
    result.append("none")
for i, j in zip(list_strings[:-1], list_strings[1:]):
    if j == s:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['none', 'sandy', 'harry', 'debra']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are porbably a thousand ways of doing that. One might be using a list comprehension and enumerate as

```py
def get_before(search_name:str, names:list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [names[i-1] if i > 0 else 'none' for i, name in enumerate(names) if name == search_name]

get_before('john', list_string)
```